# Getting registry keys with JMI

Tags: java, windows, regedit

I have to know how to use JMI (Java Metadata Interface) to obtain Registry keys on Windows, through regedit. How can this be done? Has someone used JMI for this? Or is there another method in Java to access the Windows Registry?

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing, but I'd consider another way.  You should not have to depend on registry keys.

Comment: I must obtain registry keys and I should do it with regedit, but I would need administrator rights through JMI

Comment: You don't say why you must obtain registry keys.  I wouldn't give you admin rights on my machine; it cannot work.  Think of a better solution.

Comment: regedit is a built in application, if you must use it then why not simply use it?  I think you want instead to programmatically get the key values without regedit.  In that case you need to know the syntax of registry queries.